# Hide cancel button on picker in android in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, picker

As the question says, is there any way to hide the Cancel button for the picker in xamarin.forms. There is no issue with the iOS as as the Cancel option is not visible but in android I need to hide that cancel option.

I am using Xamarin.forms version=2.4.0.282

Comment: There is no way of doing this with default Xamarin.Forms. You would have to implement a picker of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the information @GeraldVersluis, Can we know either user taps on ok or cancel. Actually I need some fuctionality has to done while tapping on OK, onselectedItemChanged event works fine when items are changed only if noting is selected among the list on picker it displays the first item is selected by default so if tap on OK then onselectedItemChanged  is not firing. If I use Unfocuss for cancel also it is behaving like a ok

Comment: I don't think so... There is the `Focused` and `Unfocused` event. You might be able to hook into the `Unfocused` event and check if the selected index == -1. Then the user exited without choosing an option. Not sure if it works, but it's worth a shot and as far as I can tell the only option.